# Receiving KeyNotFoundError Dictionary key not found: status when using the .click method

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently trying to learn VBA in Excel and I've written a simple procedure where I should be able to launch Chrome and click on a button. Problem is that I'm getting a *Run-time error '0': KeyNotFoundError Dictionary key not found:status* whenever I try to use the `.click` method.

I downloaded the Selenium Basic from the following site https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/ activated the reference in VBA and downloaded the latest chromedriver

```
Sub driver()

    Dim driver As New Selenium.WebDriver
    Set driver = New Selenium.WebDriver

    driver.Start "chrome"
    driver.Get "http://www.google.com"
    Set Element = driver.FindElementByName("btnI")
    Element.Click

End Sub
```

This is just a simple code where I launch Chrome and go to Google and click the "I feel Lucky" button.

Comment: Not the problem, but don't `Dim ... As New` if you do `Set ... = New ...` on the next line. In fact, avoid `Dim ... As New` whenever possible: it makes an auto-instantiated object, and that comes with side-effects you don't need in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test for firing that button and I needed to use javascript

```
driver.ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('[name=btnI]').click();"
```

If the error remains I suggest checking [chromedriver.exe is the right version for your Chrome browser](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and do a selenium re-install and check the selenium type reference as usual in the VBE.

Comment: This line worked. I guess I'll start using this from now until I find an alternative. I'm not sure why the previous code would give me an error like that.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Chrome is throwing "KeyNotFoundError Dictionary key not found:status" error.

Try replacing your Chromedriver with version 2.46. Here is the link: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/

Below is the code I have tried and it worked perfectly fine for me. Let us know if this solution worked for you! :)

```
   Sub driver()

        Dim driver As New Selenium.WebDriver
        Set driver = New Selenium.WebDriver

        driver.Start "chrome"
        driver.Get "http://www.google.com"
        driver.FindElementByCss("#tsf > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.FPdoLc.VlcLAe > center > input[type=submit]:nth-child(2)").Click

    End Sub
```